# Django .values() after F() expression filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

It seems that Django can not group values after you use a filter with an F() expression. For example:

(models.py)

```
class Athlete(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class TrainingSession(models.Model):
    training_date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(Athlete)

class Run(models.Model):
    run_time = models.IntegerField()
    training = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSession)
```

(views.py)
I want the number of runners for every location where they had their best run.

```
r = Run.objects.all()

# Annotate the best time from the training session and filter
r = r.annotate(best_run_time = Min('trainingsession__run__run_time'))
r = r.filter(run_time = F('best_run_time'))

# Group by location
r = r.values('location')
r = r.annotate( athlete_count = Count('trainingsession_athlete', distinct=True))
```

When I don't use the `F()` expression, the `.values('location')` will group the result per location. However, when I use it, every location is given multiple time with an athlete_count of 1.

Comment: How can you get "number of runners for every location where they had their best run"? (only one have best_runtime for location)

Comment: Yes, but for a certain location, multiple runners could have their best run.

Comment: What you will do If time in two locations will be same for one athlet? Should It count him in both locations? I think so, just clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `r.annotate(best_run_time = Min('trainingsession__run__run_time'))` will annotate a different time to every `Run` object which is not what you expect. You want to include everything in the queryset, but annotating does it for each object separately, so if a `Run` object has a `run_time` of 10 units, then 10 is also annotated. What you really need is `aggregate()` that you can use like this:

```
><> best = Run.objects.all().aggregate(Min('run_time'))
><> best
>>> {'run_time__min': 10}
```

Your query could work like this:

```
Run.objects.filter(run_time=best['run_time__min']).values('location')
```

There are some problems with Django querysets when using `F`, annotations and filtering, but without knowing which Django version you are using, it's kinda hard to point you in the correct direction.